# Is it possible to make a inetOrgPerson a member of a posixGroup in ldap php using active directory

Tags: php, ldap, lamp

Is it possible to make a inetOrgPerson a member of a posixgroup rather than added a manual entry inside of cn, im using php and ldap but i seem to come across this:

```
 Modify: Object class violation
```

code:

```
 $ldap = ldap_connect("localhost") or die("Unable to connect to server.");
 ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
 $dn = "cn=admin,dc=*******,dc=com";

 ldap_bind($ldap,$dn,"*****") or die("Unable to connect to server..");
 $dn = "cn=********,cn=*********,cn=*********,ou=A*******,dc=********,dc=com";

      $entry["cn"] = "MerPaul";
      $entry["objectClass"] = "inetOrgPerson";

      ldap_mod_add($ldap,$dn,$entry);
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And objectClass in LDAP has optional and mandatory fields. inetOrgPerson is no exception.

The required fields of inetOrgPerson are `sn` and `cn`.

```
  $entry["cn"] = "MerPaul";
  $entry["sn"] = "Joe"
  $entry["objectClass"] = "inetOrgPerson";

  ldap_mod_add($ldap,$dn,$entry);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have just changed the code to reflect this and i get the same error.

Comment: You should get more information by using the command line LDAP client. For example without the sn attribute I get ldap_add: Object class violation (65) additional info: object class 'inetOrgPerson' requires attribute 'sn'. But with it it works for me.

Comment: The command line tool for this is: ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=*******,dc=com -W

Comment: does this add a member to the group so i can query it using memberof?

Comment: Just by adding this object you did not make it a member of anything. You have to update the group you want to insert it by adding another member attribute there. (Note: if not already done you have to update your OpenLDAP configuration to activate the memberOf overlay.)

Comment: ok can you point me in the diretcion of how to do that please?

Comment: How to do what? Enabling the overlay: http://serverfault.com/questions/73213/how-do-i-configure-reverse-group-membership-maintenance-on-an-openldap-server
Using memberof: Just create the group as a different LDAP object and add all members of the group using the "member: <DN of the member>" attribute.